# label using textpath does not appear in D3 directed graph

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am sort of new to D3 and javascript. I am working off the example here: https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459

I am trying to add a label to all the edges in my graph based on data. It seems like I've added the labels correctly at least when I inspect the element, all the text elements show up correctly. However, the actual labels don't appear in the diagram. The weird part is, if I edit the HTML element using inspect element and simply add a new line and come out of editing mode, the labels suddenly show up.

Could anyone help me figure out what is going on? I've already spent many hours trying to debug this to no avail.

I read many threads online and the only thing I've got is that I need to add the labels in my tick function. However, I don't have a tick function in the code and I don't think that is the issue.

```
var paths = thisGraph.paths;
paths.enter()

          .append("path")
          .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
          .attr("id", function (d) {
              return "arrow_path_" + d.source.id + "_" + d.target.id
          })
          .classed("link", true)
          .attr("d", function (d) {
              return thisGraph.updateArrows.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
          })   
          .on("mousedown", function (d) {
              thisGraph.pathMouseDown.call(thisGraph, d3.select(this), d);
          })
          .on("mouseup", function (d) {
              state.mouseDownLink = null;
          });
var labels = d3.select('#edges');
      var edgelabels = labels.selectAll("text")
                    .data(thisGraph.edges)
                    .enter()
      .append("text")
      .style("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr({
                'class': 'edgelabel',
                'id': function (d, i) {return 'edgelabel' + i},
                'font-size': 10,
                'fill': '#aaa'
            })
            .append("textpath")
            .attr("class", "textpath")
            .attr("startOffset", "55.76%")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                return "#arrow_path_" + d.source.id + "_" + d.target.id
            })
            .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
```

```html
<g id="edges"><path id="arrow_path_0_1" class="link" d="M738,430L738,423.1875" style="marker-end: url(&quot;#end-arrow&quot;);"></path><path id="arrow_path_1_2" class="link" d="M677.015625,484.5L660.51171875,484.5C644.0078125,484.5,611,484.5,594.49609375,484.5C577.9921875,484.5,577.9921875,484.5,577.9921875,512.5833333333334C577.9921875,540.6666666666666,577.9921875,596.8333333333333,577.9921875,624.9166666666666L577.9921875,653" style="marker-end: url(&quot;#end-arrow&quot;);"></path><path id="arrow_path_1_3" class="link" d="M677.015625,484.5L713.8776041666666,484.5C750.7395833333333,484.5,824.4635416666666,484.5,861.3255208333333,484.5C898.1875,484.5,898.1875,484.5,898.1874999999999,512.5833333333334C898.1875,540.6666666666666,898.1875,596.8333333333333,898.1874999999999,624.9166666666666L898.1875,653" style="marker-end: url(&quot;#end-arrow&quot;);"></path><path id="arrow_path_3_4" class="link" d="M898.1875,703L898.1874999999999,712.1666666666666C898.1875,721.3333333333333,898.1875,739.6666666666666,898.1874999999999,748.8333333333334C898.1875,758,898.1875,758,881.8906249999999,758C865.59375,758,833,758,816.7031249999999,758L800.40625,758" style="marker-end: url(&quot;#end-arrow&quot;);"></path><path id="arrow_path_4_5" class="link" d="M738.1875,783L738.1875,795.9166666666666C738.1875,808.8333333333333,738.1875,834.6666666666666,738.1875,847.5833333333333C738.1875,860.5,738.1875,860.5,753.9166666666666,860.4999999999999C769.6458333333333,860.5,801.1041666666666,860.5,816.8333333333333,860.4999999999999L832.5625,860.5" style="marker-end: url(&quot;#end-arrow&quot;);"></path><path id="arrow_path_5_6" class="link" d="M738.0078125,908L738.0078125,908.6666666666665C738.0078125,909.3333333333333,738.0078125,910.6666666666666,738.0078125,911.3333333333333C738.0078125,912,738.0078125,912,750.37109375,912C762.734375,912,787.4609374999999,912,799.82421875,912L812.1875,912" style="marker-end: url(&quot;#end-arrow&quot;);"></path><path id="arrow_path_6_7" class="link" d="M664.28125,912L676.4830729166666,912C688.6848958333333,912,713.0885416666666,912,725.2903645833334,912C737.4921875,912,737.4921875,912,737.4921875,922.1666666666666C737.4921875,932.3333333333333,737.4921875,952.6666666666666,737.4921875,962.8333333333333L737.4921875,973" style="marker-end: url(&quot;#end-arrow&quot;);"></path><text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel0" font-size="10" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;"><textpath class="textpath" startOffset="55.76%" xlink:href="#arrow_path_0_1" style="text-anchor: end;">1</textpath></text><text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel1" font-size="10" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;"><textpath class="textpath" startOffset="55.76%" xlink:href="#arrow_path_1_2" style="text-anchor: end;">2</textpath></text><text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel2" font-size="10" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;"><textpath class="textpath" startOffset="55.76%" xlink:href="#arrow_path_1_3" style="text-anchor: end;">3</textpath></text><text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel3" font-size="10" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;"><textpath class="textpath" startOffset="55.76%" xlink:href="#arrow_path_3_4" style="text-anchor: end;">4</textpath></text><text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel4" font-size="10" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;"><textpath class="textpath" startOffset="55.76%" xlink:href="#arrow_path_4_5" style="text-anchor: end;">5</textpath></text><text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel5" font-size="10" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;"><textpath class="textpath" startOffset="55.76%" xlink:href="#arrow_path_5_6" style="text-anchor: end;">6</textpath></text><text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel6" font-size="10" fill="#aaa" style="pointer-events: none;"><textpath class="textpath" startOffset="55.76%" xlink:href="#arrow_path_6_7" style="text-anchor: end;">7</textpath></text></g>
```

I do expect the labels to show up. What am I missing?

Comment: You've a typo it's textPath, not textpath.

Comment: Wow, thanks that worked! I knew svg was case sensitive but was careless with this. Thank you so so much!